# Measure height of last text character, calculate Italics correction

Tags: luatex, italic-correction

This applies to running text, not math or diagrams. I am using TeXlive 2023
on Linux, compiling with `lualatex`. UTF-8, Left-to-right text, Latin-based letters
plus the usual typographic support (I expect this will also apply to Greek and Cyrillic).

If I uderstand how Italics correct `\/` works, it dates back to pre-lualatex days,
and assumes that the fonts (probably Type 1) each come with `tfm` support.
The value of correction is read from the `tfm` (it is a binary file).
Contemporary OpenType fonts, especially those that are not part of the LaTeX
font distribution, do not have that.

Searching here at SE, the only things I found on his topic dated to many years ago,
when `lualatex` was new. Also, those questions involved math.

I imagine that per-character Italic correction could be determined on-the-fly,
by reading the final character of a text string, and measuring its height in a box.
That does not require Lua code. Depending on the box height, extra space would
be added after the Italic string. Thus, letters at X-height would get a different
dorrection than letters at X-height (including letters with ascenders). This could
also compensate for diacriticals.

The amount of added space could be generic, or specified per-font by the user,
or possibly (with Lua support) by measuring the right bearing. But this last method
might extend compile time too much?

It might also be possible to look at the next-to-last character, if the last
character is period or comma.

MWE showing the measurement, in a Regular font. The `\foobar` would only contain text, but some of that text might be expandable macros that resolve to text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % If compiling with lualatex
\usepackage{xstring}
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}
\def\foobar{foo bar} % case 1
\StrRight{\foobar}{1}[\barfoo]
\barfoo\savebox\mybox{\barfoo}\the\ht\mybox\typeout{completed case 1}
\def\foobar{f\'o\'o bar\'o} % case 2, correctly gets the final odieresis.
\StrRight{\foobar}{1}[\barfoo]
\barfoo\savebox\mybox{\barfoo}\the\ht\mybox\typeout{completed case 2}
\def\foobar{fo\kern-.5pto bar} % case 3, using kern does not hurt.
\StrRight{\foobar}{1}[\barfoo]
\barfoo\savebox\mybox{\barfoo}\the\ht\mybox\typeout{completed case 3}
\def\foobar{foo\\bar} % case 4, with double-backslash linebreak.
\StrRight{\foobar}{1}[\barfoo]
\barfoo\savebox\mybox{\barfoo}\the\ht\mybox\typeout{completed case 4}
\long\def\foobar{foo\par bar} % case 5, with manual paragraph ending.
\StrRight{\foobar}{1}[\barfoo]
\barfoo\savebox\mybox{\barfoo}\the\ht\mybox\typeout{completed case 5}
\long\def\foobar{foo

bar} % case 6, with double-linespace paragraph.
\StrRight{\foobar}{1}[\barfoo]
\barfoo\savebox\mybox{\barfoo}\the\ht\mybox\typeout{completed case 6}
%\def\foobar{foo\linebreak bar} % Does not work. Not really a problem.
\end{document}
```

My question: Am I on the right track? Or is there some other method that I do
not know about? Or, is this kind of thing already in `lualatex` ?

Incidentally, I used `xstring` because I already use that package for
many other purposes.

Comment: I don't think the height is really the issue, `L`  might be taller than `f` but almost certainly `f` will need a larger italic correction

Comment: I'd avoid xstring there are usually better, often expandable, functions predefined in latex, in the L3 programming layer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I see that there would be issues with L versus f, and many others. Since I work in a limited character set, it would be possible to fork according to the actual character, rather than its metrics. But your answer, below, shows that none of that is worth pursuing, as the problem is already solved. Also: I use `xstring` vecuase it is easy to understand, and I have not (yet) have expansion problems. Yet! Will have a look at what L3 does, exentually,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luatex or xetex take the italic correction from the OpenType font metrics and expose them in the same way as etex does with tfm metrics.

luatex shows

```
> 0.0pt.
l.7 \showthe\fontcharic\font`X
                            
? 
> 0.0pt.
l.9 \showthe\fontcharic\font`L
                            
? 
> 1.02pt.
l.13 \showthe\fontcharic\font`X
                             
? 
> 0.17pt.
l.15 \showthe\fontcharic\font`L
                             
?
```

for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % If compiling with lualatex

\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}

\showthe\fontcharic\font`X

\showthe\fontcharic\font`L

\itshape

\showthe\fontcharic\font`X

\showthe\fontcharic\font`L

\end{document}
```

showing the italic correction is 0 in the upright font and positive in the italic font (but not closely related to the character height)

If you have the string in a macro and want the final italic correction, you can use `\/` and see how much it adds.

```
\def\foo{abcdef}
\sbox0{\upshape \foo\/\showthe\lastkern}
\sbox0{\itshape \foo\/\showthe\lastkern}
```

produces

```
> 0.0pt.
<argument> \upshape \foo \/\showthe \lastkern 
                                   
l.18 \sbox0{\upshape \foo\/\showthe\lastkern}
                                           
? 
> 1.65pt.
<argument> \itshape \foo \/\showthe \lastkern 
                                   
l.19 \sbox0{\itshape \foo\/\showthe\lastkern}
                                           
?
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I really needed to know. It is already done, so no need for me to reinvent the wheel (using wooden wheels). When I searched before asking, what I found was previous to the methods you described above.

Comment: @rallg not sure what you mean by previous, but everything I show here has been available in xetex and luatex since they started decades ago

Comment: "Previous" in the sense that I didn't know. Still learning. I usually find information by looking at what others asked or did, and almost all of that involved math-related issues.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I like it. :)